# How to write Composable function using Kotlin Functional (SAM) Interface

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming, android-jetpack-compose, functional-interface

We can write functional interfaces in Kotlin like this - [function-interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html)

```
fun interface Sum {
    fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}

val sumImpl = Sum { a, b ->
    return@Sum a + b
}

val testSum = sumImpl.add(4, 5)
```

How can we write Jetpack Composable function in same way? Below code is not working.
`

```
fun interface SampleText {
    @Composable
    fun text(data : String)
}

val textImpl = SampleText { data ->
    return@SampleText @Composable { Text(data) }
}

@Composable
fun testText() = textImpl.text("Data")
```

I have tried this as well, but this also didn't work.

```
fun interface SampleText {
    fun text(data : String) : @Composable () -> Unit
}

val textImpl = SampleText { data ->
    @Composable { Text(data) }
}

@Composable
fun testText() = textImpl.text("Data")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is not compiling in its lambda form because your interface function returns a `Unit` and your'e actually having a `Type mismatch` error, its just weird the compiler reports `Internal Error` when you try to return a `@Composable` annotated function, but the issue becomes clear if you simply return something like a `String`.

[image]
vs
[image]

To solve your first version, either you fully declare an object of the class like this (though its useless since you want a lambda version of your SAM interface not an actual object in the first place)

```
val textImpl = object: SampleText {
    
    @Composable
    override fun text(data: String) {
        Text(data)
    }
}
```

, but it will work just by simply calling the testText() function like this.

```
testText()
```

Or change it to your second version.

---

Now for your second version, since your interface returns a `@Composable` lambda, you have to invoke it as well in the call-site, making two function invocations to make it work,

```
testText()() // two invocations
```

first call invokes your `testText()` function, second pair of parenthesis invokes the `@Composable` lambda from your interface.

Or simply call `.invoke()`

```
testText().invoke() // just call the .invoke() of the returned composable lambda
```

Either of the implementations and calls display the text "Data"

[image]

Comment: Thanks @z.y, second approach is more better.